# NavigationController is nil in Swift after Presenting Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am presenting a UINavigationController programmatically like this:

```
let homeViewController = HomeViewController.loadFromNibNamed(nibNamed: "HomeViewController")
let homeNavigationViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeViewController!)
self.present(homeNavigationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but then in HomeViewController there is a call for `self.navigationController!.navigationBar` where the navigationController is nil?

Comment: When exactly is that line executed?

Comment: In viewDidLoad, so I guess it is because the HomeViewController is being loaded before the navigationController and therefore it is nil, but how do I go about doing this programmatically then with xibs?

Comment: This should not lead to a crash in `viewDidLoad`. I think the problem is somewhere else... What are you trying to do with the navigation bar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to print or use self.navigationController?.navigationBar in viewWillAppear().

I think navigationController will be optional.